# jquery copy paste numbers to fillup input fileds

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, copy-paste, one-time-password

I have tried this but on keyup not working to jump next input but backspace working find.

**Looking features:**

- On Keyup jump to next input
- On Backspace jump to prev input
- Paste the code and distribute codes to all input fields steps by maxLength

```js
$('.col').on('input', '.press', function() {
    if (this.value.length >= this.maxLength) {
        $(this).parent().next('div.col').find('input').focus();
      
    }
}).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 8 && !this.value) {
        $(this).prev().find('input').focus();
    }
});
```

```css
body{display: flex;}
.form-control{width: 70px;
margin-right: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="press form-control" name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="press form-control"  name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="press form-control"  name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="press form-control"  name="code" maxlength="1" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've added an attribute tabindex on the input type text field. The tabindex attribute identifies each next tab index to be focus. Javascript keyup event will now jump to the next input which I increment it to the current focus index.

I've also added a paste event listener on the input type text and get the length of the data then paste the value on it.

```js
$(function(){

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener("paste", function(p)
{
    var dataLength = p.clipboardData.getData('text').length;
    
    for(var i = 1; i <= dataLength; i++)
    {   
        $("input[tabindex='"+ i + "']").val(p.clipboardData.getData('text')[i - 1]);
        
        if (this.value.length >= this.maxLength) 
        {       
             $("input[tabindex='"+ i + "']").focus();   
        }
    }
});

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(e) 
{

    if (this.value.length >= this.maxLength) 
    {
        if(e.keyCode !== 9 && e.keyCode !== 16)
        {
            var tabIndex =  this.tabIndex + 1;  
                $("input[tabindex='"+ this.tabIndex + "']").val(this.value);
                $("input[tabindex='"+ tabIndex + "']").focus(); 
        }
    } 
    else
    {
        if(e.keyCode === 8)
        {
            var tabIndex =  this.tabIndex - 1;
                $("input[tabindex='"+ tabIndex + "']").focus();
        }
        
    }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="press form-control" name="code" maxlength="1" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="press form-control"  name="code" maxlength="1" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="press form-control"  name="code" maxlength="1" tabindex="3" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="press form-control"  name="code" maxlength="1" tabindex="4" autocomplete="off">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Smaller, I have edited the code and add paste event listener. I have problem on the focus when you copy paste it will focus on the 3rd input but I think you can fix it. You can also improve my code above if there anything to add on it. :)

Comment: Hi @Smaller, I just updated the code above. Did you managed to run it? Let me know if you have other problem on it.

Comment: i got another issue with your code. copy and paste abcd and then put the cursor on the 1st input and hit tab key, its jump to 3rd input.

Comment: Hi @Smaller, I have now updated the code and add  && e.keyCode !== 16 to no to skip on before or after the current tab.